# Notation for an asymptotic binary relation

Tags: analysis, notation, asymptotics

Is there any standard notational convention for an asymptotic binary relation $R$ between two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ where $f(x)=_{R}g(x)$ if and only if $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|=0$? I have to use such a relation often, and the ordinary asymptotic equivalence relation $f(x)\sim g(x)$ is not sufficient for my proof.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

$$
f(x) = g(x) + o(1)
$$

is equivalent to

$$
\lim |f(x) - g(x)| = 0,
$$

and of course the limit needs to be supplied in both cases (e.g. $x \to 0$, or $x \to \infty$, etc.).

Comment: The problem is that I would have to carry the o(1) term around if I don't specify any binary relation throughout my whole derivation. The o(1) notation has helped me write something more succinctly, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find
a standard notation,
and I can't think of one
right now,
you could *define*
a relation and call it
$f(x)\sim_0 g(x)
$,
or something like it,
to be what you want.
Note the "$_0$".

Comment: That's what I was planning on doing if I couldn't find any standard notation, but I was hesitant about coming up with new notation for such a seemingly standard relation.